# Joining Solution using Co-Group by SideInput Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have 2 Tables to Join, its a `Left Join`. Below is the two Condition, how my pipeline is working.

The job is running in batch mode and its all User data and we want to process in Google Dataflow.

**Day 1:**

Table A: 5000000 Records. (Size 3TB)

Table B: 200 Records. (Size 1GB)

Both Tables Joined through `SideInput` where `TableB` Data was Taken as `SideInput` and it was working fine.

**Day 2:**

Table A: 5000010 Records. (Size 3.001TB)

Table B: 20000 Records.  (Size 100GB)

On second day my pipeline is slowing down because `SideInput` uses cache and my cache size got exhausted, because of size of `TableB` got Increased.

So I tried Using `Co-Group by`, but `Day 1` data processing was pretty slow with a Log: `Having 10000 plus values on Single Key.`

So is there any better performant way to perform the Joining when Hotkey get introduced.

Comment: Have you looked for this interesting article https://nl.devoteam.com/en/blog-post/implementing-left-join-google-dataflow-apache-beam/ ?

Comment: @muscat I have gone through the article. But as I told above My jobs become slowed and send the log, in stackdriver as "Having 10000 plus values on Single Key". Because Left Table has the Same key as Table B for ~20K records. Which makes the pipeline slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the performance can drop precipitously once table B no longer fits into cache, and there aren't many good solutions. The slowdown in using CoGroupByKey is not solely due to having many values on a single key, but also the fact that you're now shuffling (aka grouping) Table A at all (which was avoided when using a side input).

Depending on the distribution of your keys, one possible mitigation could be to process your hot keys into a path that does the side-input joining as before, and your long-tail keys into a GoGBK. This could be done by producing a truncated TableB' as a side input, and your ParDo would attempt to look up the key emitting to one PCollection if it was found in TableB' and another if it was not [1]. One would then pass this second PCollection to a CoGroupByKey with all of TableB, and flatten the results.

[1] https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs